# Вычислить 20 значений функций для изменяющегося аргумента

Tags: delphi, pascal, turbopascal

Для аргумента X , изменяющегося от –0.6 с шагом 0.05 вычислить 20 значений функций.
[image: Для аргумента X , изменяющегося от –0.6 с шагом 0.05 вычислить 20 значений функций.]

```
PROGRAM IPR;
Uses Crt;
Const
eps1 =  0.01;
eps2 =  0.01;
eps3 = 0.001;
a    =  -0.6;
b    =  0.05;
N    =    20;

Var
k1, k2, k3, i: Integer;
f1, f2_1, f2_2, f2_3, step, slag, x: Real;
BEGIN
ClrScr;
writeln('______________________________________________________________');
writeln('|        |             |e= 0.01   |e = 0.001  | e = 0.0001 |');
writeln('| x      | f1(x)       |----------------------|----------- |');
writeln('|        |             |f2(x) | N |f2(x)  | N | f2(x)  | N |');
writeln('|________|_____________|______|___|_______|___|________|___|');
x := a;
for i := 1 to N do
begin
f1 := ((1-x*x)*ln((1-x)/(1+x))+2*(x*x+1)*arctan(1/x))/8;
step := x*x*x*x;
f2_1 := 0;
k1 := 0;
repeat
inc(k1);
step := step*x*x*x;
slag := step/((4*k1+1)/(4*k1+3));
f2_1 := f2_1+slag;
until abs(slag)<=eps1;
f2_2 := f2_1;
k2 :=k1;
repeat
inc(k2);
step := step*x*x*x;
slag := step/((4*k2+1)/(4*k1+3));
f2_2 := f2_2+slag;
until abs(slag)<=eps2;
f2_3 := f2_2;
k3 :=k2;
repeat
inc(k3);
step :=step*x*x*x;
slag :=step/((4*k3+1)*(4*k3+3));
f2_3 :=f2_3+slag;
until abs(slag)<=eps3;
writeln('|  ', x:5:2,' | ',f1:12:9,'| ',f2_1:5:2,'| ',
k1:2,'| ',f2_2:6:3,'| ',k2:2,'| ',f2_3:7:4,'| ', k3:2,'|');
x :=x+b;
end;
write('-------------------------------------------------------------');
ReadKey
END.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первой формуле ошибка:
должно быть **f1 := ((1-x*x)*ln((1-x)/(1+x))+2*(x*x+1)*arctan(x))/8;**

Плюс, зачем городить столько repeat'ов? Достаточно (учитывая, что паскаль, а не дельфи):

```
for i:=0 to 19 do
  begin
    x:=-0.6 + i*0.05;
    f1 := ((1-sqr(x))*ln((1-x)/(1+x))+2*(sqr(x)+1)*arctan(x))/8; //используем функцию sqr вместо x*x
    k:=0;
    f2:=0;
    repeat
       df:=exp(ln(x)*(4k+3))/(4k+1)/(4k+3); // нет в паскале функции возведения в степень, используем свою через экспоненту и логарифм.
       f2:=f2+df;
       inc(k);
    until  df < 1e-10; // точность предела, можно регулировать
    writeln('|  ', x:5:2,' | ',f1:12:9,'| ',f2:5:2);
  end;
```

Если же дельфи, то **df:=power(x,4k+3)/(4k+1)/(4k+3);**

как вариант, критерий точности предела можно выразить так:

```
until df*1e+5 <= f2; // цифра 5 означает,  что цикл считается с точностью до 5 знака включительно.
```